# Error Creating Text File Java

Tags: java, file, text, metadata-extractor

I'm using the [metadata extractor API](http://metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/) to extract metadata from an image. I'm then using Java to create a .txt file with all the data. However, when I run the file, I have nullpointexception.

I know something is outputting as it prints out in the output box provided in NetBeans.

Class that creates the file:

```
private void metadataImageButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                 
    System.out.println(MetaData.getTags());
    try {
    File report;
    report = new File("report.txt");

        report.createNewFile();
        FileWriter kmlStream = new FileWriter("report.txt");
        try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(kmlStream)) {
            out.write(MetaData.allTags);
            statusUpdateMessage.setText("Report file created");
            System.out.println("New file \"Report.txt\" has been created to the current directory");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MetaDataExtractor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Retrieves all metadata

```
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(jpegFile);

    for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
        for (Tag allTags : directory.getTags()) {
            System.out.println(allTags);
        }
    }
} catch (ImageProcessingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MetaData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MetaData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return allTags;
```

My first thought was to have the return type as a String, but it wouldn't allow me to do it. Any suggestions are welcome as I'm not strong with Java. [Here are the errors](http://pastebin.com/pbRfkPee)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By just reading the source code of java.io.Writer, that comes with the JDK, you can deduce that you're writing a null String to the Writer, and that causes the NullPointerException. This happens at `MetaDataExtractor.metadataImageButtonMouseClicked()`, in the file `MetaDataExtractor.java` at line 541.

Check that your Strings aren't null before writing them.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the first lines of your error trace:

```
at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
at MetaDataExtractor.metadataImageButtonMouseClicked(MetaDataExtractor.java:541)
```

The problem is in the `metadataImageButtonMouseClicked(e)`, particularly at **line 541** which instruction do you find there? which variables are involved? This should help